# ComboBox selection not appearing at first click Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am writing a script in Excel VBA where I am working in a `Userform`. In this `Userform`, I have two `ComboBox`, `ComboBox1` and `ComboBox4`. Both `ComboBox` are a drop-down list that is populated in the script.

I have made it so that `ComboBox4` gets populated  after and depending on the user input on `ComboBox1`. I have written the following code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

   With ComboBox1
        .AddItem "Afghanistan"
        .AddItem "Åland Islands"
        .AddItem "Albania"
        .AddItem "Algeria"
        .AddItem "American Samoa"
        .AddItem "Andorra"
   End With

   With ComboBox4
        .AddItem "Africa"
        .AddItem "Americas"
        .AddItem "Asia"
        .AddItem "Europe"
        .AddItem "MENA"
        .AddItem "Other"
   End With
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

If ComboBox1 = "" Then
    ComboBox4 = vbNullString: ComboBox4.Enabled = True
Else
    Dim index As Integer
     index = ComboBox1.ListIndex

Select Case index
    Case Is = 0
        ComboBox4.Value = "Asia"
        ComboBox4.Enabled = False
    Case Is = 1
        ComboBox4.Value = "Europe"
        ComboBox4.Enabled = False
    Case Is = 2
        ComboBox4.Value = "Europe"
        ComboBox4.Enabled = False
    Case Is = 3
        ComboBox4.Value = "MENA"
        ComboBox4.Enabled = False
    Case Is = 4
        ComboBox4.Value = "Asia"
        ComboBox4.Enabled = False
    Case Is = 5
        ComboBox4.Value = "Europe"
        ComboBox4.Enabled = False
End Select

End If

End Sub
```

Everything seems to be working fine. The only thig is that `ComboBox1` has a strange and annoying behaviour: Whenever I open the `Userform` and select an option from the drop-down list of `ComboBox1` or start typing on it it doesn't select the option or type the letter unless I do it twice. So, if I select an option from the list, it remains blank until I select it again; if I start typing, the first letter I typed never appears, just those from the second on.

I don't understand what is going on and have researched on it, albeit unsuccessfully. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I assume by `combobox2` you mean `combobox4`? This appears to work ok for me. Is this the complete code???

Comment: Sorry, yes. `ComboBox4`. It is the complete code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ComboBox1_AfterUpdate()`event instead of `ComboBox1_Change()` event

Answer (score 1):

in your narrative you're telling about `ComboBox1` and `CombBox2`, while your code shows `ComboBox1` and `CombBox4`

just check you're not messing things up

then, maybe you have some `ComboBox2_Change` (or `ComboBox4_Change`) that alters your code `ComboBox1` value and thus interfere with `ComboBox1_Change`

BTW you may adopt a shorter code for `ComboBox1_Change`, like follows:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If ComboBox1 = "" Then
        ComboBox4 = vbNullString: ComboBox4.Enabled = True
    Else
        ComboBox4.Enabled = False
        Select Case ComboBox1.ListIndex
            Case 0, 4
                ComboBox4.Value = "Asia"
            Case 1, 2, 5
                ComboBox4.Value = "Europe"
            Case 3
                ComboBox4.Value = "MENA"
            Case Else
                ComboBox4.Enabled = True
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

where you would change all `ComboBox4` occurrences to `ComboBox2`

Comment: @franciscofcosta, any feedback?